# How to make suspend work without the screen staying black afterwards?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, hibernate, backlight

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, and whenever I try to resume my computer after suspending it, everything starts up fine except my screen, which remains black (no backlight). My laptop even responds to keyboard presses and mouse clicks as if it's awake, I just can't see anything.

I tried using this command to suspend:

```
sudo pm-suspend --quirk-dpms-on
```

When I did that, my laptop was able to resume successfully, screen included, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a simple one:

Add `pm-suspend --quirk-dpms-on` to the `/var/cache/pm-utils/last_known_working.quirkdb` file.

Reboot and it should work flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, I knew there must be some way to get Ubuntu to use suspend with that quirk by default. I have a problem though, there is no file called last_known_working.quirkdb in that directory. Should I just create that file in the directory? Or look for it in another directory?

Comment: @AshourBadine Create it. I had a similar nVidia glitch (they suck with linux) and the file didn't exist. It should work.

Comment: Alright just did and restarted, it worked perfectly, thanks a lot man! How come this works, by the way, if you don't mind me asking? How did you find out that this is the way to get Ubuntu to, by default, use this suspend command?

Comment: How this works is the `last_known_working.quirkdb` file contains the record of the LAST SUCCESSFUL sleep operation. Since Ubuntu isn't that good of keeping tabs of this, adding the working suspend code `--quirk-dpms-on` to it will make Ubuntu use it for all suspends in the future.