# Lubuntu MacBook no screen backlight after resume/wake

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, macbook, hibernate, backlight

I'm running Lubuntu 15.10 on a MacBook Intel Core2Duo.

After suspending/hibernating and then resuming/waking the screen's backlight does not come on. With a bright enough light, one can see what the screen is displaying. To get the backlight back on, I reboot for now.

**Solutions to similar posted problems that I've tried:**

There are 3 solutions in this link. One is posted on the linked page, one is in a link to thecodecentral.com on that same page, and one is on the first page of this link. I've tried each of them. They all seem to work off the idea that `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci_hcd` needs to be unbound and bound at the time of the sleep/hibernation and wake/resume, but I found no `ehci_hcd` in my `/sys/bus/pci/drivers`. However, I did find `ehci-pci` in that same directory, so I replaced all instances of `ehci_hcd` with `ehci-pci` and filled in the appropriate values for what I assume is the device address(?)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1444822&page=5

I tried the suspend command suggested by Ashour here, but it doesn't work for me, so I didn't see any point in trying to put it in a script.

[How to make suspend work without the screen staying black afterwards?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511601/how-to-make-suspend-work-without-the-screen-staying-black-afterwards)

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

edit:

I've discovered that laptop no longer sleeps properly when I close the lid. Closing the lid does not turn the screen off, though during the process of lifting the lid up again, there is one or two points where the screen flips off and back on again. None of this interrupts the backlighting, though using the suspend command through the power menu or terminal still results in no backlighting.

Here is the code that I have currently added from the solutions listed above:

```
#!/bin/sh
#File: "/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_my_custom_ehci-hcd"
case "${1}" in
        hibernate|suspend)
              # Unbind ehci-pci for first device 0000:00:1a.7:
               echo -n "0000:00:1a.7" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
              # Unbind ehci-pci for second device 0000:00:1d.7:
               echo -n "0000:00:1d.7" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/unbind
        ;;
        resume|thaw)
              # Bind ehci-pci for first device 0000:00:1a.7:
              echo -n "0000:00:1a.7" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind
              # Bind ehci-pci for second device 0000:00:1d.7:
              echo -n "0000:00:1d.7" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ehci-pci/bind
        ;;
esac
```

and also this...

```
#File: "/etc/pm/config.d/usb3-suspend-workaround"
SUSPEND_MODULES="xhci"
```

Comment: I've swapped Lubuntu for Xubuntu (installed xubuntu-desktop and uninstalled lubuntu-desktop), because xubuntu appeared to have more support and all the solutions i was finding appeared to work for xubuntu.

Nothing did work though. I have found however, that locking the screen and then closing the lid (in Xubuntu at least) does bypass this problem. Still would like to find a 'true' solution though.

Comment: Turns out that locking the screen is a poor workaround. Since the computer is still on, processes still run in the background, heat can still be generated and the fan can still turn on.