# How to change the time to change to a black screen during the login prompt

Tags: login, suspend, 17.10, gdm

Is there a way to change the timeout to change to a black screen during the login prompt?

As it is, whenever I open up the laptop and resume from suspend, after pressing a key, the login screen appears for a couple of seconds and then immediately goes black, so I have to press another key to continue with my login session. This gets aggravating pretty quickly.

Comment: Did you try this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/511601/how-to-make-suspend-work-without-the-screen-staying-black-afterwards?rq=1

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. The laptop does light up, it just has a very period of time before thinking you're afk, and goes back to black.

Comment: Possibly related -- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168830/how-to-disable-screen-power-saving-in-gdm3-login-screen and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361214/disable-gdm-suspend-on-lock-screen