# How to disable screen power saving in GDM3 login screen?

Tags: gnome, power-management, lock-screen, gdm

On the desktop login screen (GDM3) my computer will put the screens into power saving mode after 15 seconds of inactivity. I would ideally like to disable power saving in this situation, or at least lengthen the period.

I have tried disabling all power saving options that I can find in `gsettings`, both for my user and for `root`, but this has not affected the 15 second timeout.

What else can I try?

I'm running Ubuntu 19.04 with Gnome Shell 3.32.2. I have found various older questions concerned with the same issue, but they all relate to LightDM:

- [How do I prevent my display from turning off when screen is locked?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890965/how-do-i-prevent-my-display-from-turning-off-when-screen-is-locked)
- [How to disable sleep/suspend at login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/942366/how-to-disable-sleep-suspend-at-login-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 5):

This default setting (suspend at login) affects me in Pop!os 20.04. When away from home I want to login to my home PC, and it is set to boot at 6am. But that's no use when it suspends :)

This is an easy fix:

From: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=893964#22

> It's 20 minutes, and is a result of the defaults in
> gnome-settings-daemon
> 3.28 changing to comply with European and American power-saving regulations.
>
> > there appears to be no way of switching the GDM suspend behaviour off
>
> There's currently no UI for it, but if you append this to
> /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults:

```
# Automatic suspend
# =================
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power]
# - Time inactive in seconds before suspending with AC power
#   1200=20 minutes, 0=never
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=0
# - What to do after sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
#   'blank', 'suspend', 'shutdown', 'hibernate', 'interactive' or 'nothing'
sleep-inactive-ac-type='nothing'
# - As above but when on battery
# sleep-inactive-battery-timeout=1200
# sleep-inactive-battery-type='suspend'
```

> then reboot (or run "service gdm3 reload" as root), that should put
> the GDM session back to the pre-3.28 behaviour. The values are in
> seconds, with 0 meaning never; please adjust as needed.

Note: this still works in Ubuntu 21.10.
Also, if you want the screens to go into suspend mode but you don't want to suspend, set a timeout, and set the type to be 'blank'

For changes to take effect, reboot or

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

Answer (score 2):

Create /etc/dconf/profile/gdm and add:

```
user-db:user
system-db:gdm
file-db:/usr/share/gdm/greeter-dconf-defaults
```

Create /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/01-power and add:

```
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power]
sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=0
sleep-inactive-ac-type='nothing'
```

Run `sudo dconf update`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not appear to affect the monitor going into power saving mode after 15s.

Comment: Even after a cold restart? Could not test it myself.

Comment: Yes. I think something else must be responsible for invoking the DPMS state. I'm wondering if it might be hard-coded.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is configured through gsettings, I changed my answer: can you try that approach?

Answer (score 0):

`xset -dpms` disables DPMS, meaning you will see a black screen, not an off monitor. `xset +dpms` re-enables it.

`xset s 300` changes the timeout to 300 seconds.

Neither of these commands persist across logout, but you can add them to ~/.xsession.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following script as root :

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-dpms.conf <<EOF
echo '[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/dpms-stop'
EOF


cat > /usr/local/bin/dpms-stop <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
sudo xhost +si:localuser:lightdm 
sudo su lightdm -s /bin/bash <<HERE
/usr/bin/xset -dpms
exit
HERE
EOF

chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dpms-stop
```

Then reboot

Comment: Would you mind to explain what it does?

Comment: Two files are created. One conf file for lightdm, which is calling a script called dpms-stop. So this script is created, what it does is to stop dpms (power management) when lightdm is launched.

Comment: That's out of scope, OP uses GDM3, not lightdm, so this is not going to work.